# Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in, why is it empty?

Tags: php, oop, object

I follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNWArvc-uN0&index=12&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF0RicJb20da8nECQ1jFvla) step by step, but I do seem to have a mistake somewhere. Can anyone explain where my mistake is and how to fix it?

index.php

```
<?php
require 'Classes/Calculator.php';
require 'Classes/OperatorInterface.php';
require 'Classes/Adder.php';
require 'Classes/Subtractor.php';

$c = new Calculator;

$c->setOperation(new Adder);
$c->calculate(10, 50);

echo $c->getResult();
?>
```

Calculator.php

```
<?php
class Calculator{

    protected $result;

    protected $operation;

    public function setOperation(OperatorInterface $operation){
        $this->operation = $operation;
    }

    public function calculate(){
        foreach(func_get_args() as $number){
            $this->result = $this->operation->run($number, $this->$result);
        }
    }

    public function getResult(){
        return $this->result;
    }
}
?>
```

Adder.php

```
<?php
class Adder implements OperatorInterface{
    public function run($number, $result){
        return $result + $number;
    }
}
?>
```

OperatorInterface.php

```
<?php
interface OperatorInterface{
    public function run($number, $result);
}
?>
```

I just started learning OOP, so it might be a really stupid mistake, sorry in advance... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please include the exact text of the error, it's not clear from the title alone.

Comment: $this->$result should be $this->result.  You don't need the $ after the -> when referring to a member variable of the class.

Comment: @MarkH. That was the problem, thank you for your solution!

Comment: @MarkH. I take it  you will convert your comment to a (good) answer ;-) Given an answer below that didn't provide them with the actual problem. Edit: which has now been deleted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't think a typo warranted a full answer, but if you insist...

Comment: @MarkH. I thought it was fitting (and after seeing the other answer which is deleted and you may not be able to see it). I myself do post answers for questions like this whenever someone else posts an answer that didn't target the real problem and even posting them as community wikis, which I also like to do ;-)

Comment: @LexdeWilligen Mark posted an answer below; remember to mark it as solved.

Comment: @LexdeWilligen Btw, here's a pretty good tutorial on classes http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials which I happen to be reading these days; it's very well-written and also has an article on interfaces etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in `Calculator::calculate()`, `$this->$result` should be `$this->result`:

```
public function calculate(){
    foreach(func_get_args() as $number){
        $this->result = $this->operation->run($number, $this->result);
    }
}
```

You don't need the `$` after the `->` when referring to a member variable (property) of the class.